How to make a automation on react native app?
I am trying to run a automation test on my react native app with detox but there is a problem while lunching the app can any one help me with this..
using "detox": "^20.28.0"
test code using to launch the app:
describe('Example', () => { 
  beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log("awaiting launch app");
     await device.launchApp();
    console.log("done launch app");
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

});


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
